# Pass what Button was Pushed in Context Menu

Tags: android

I am currently developing a soundboard for android and I have ran into a bit of a problem. I successfully implemented a context menu that allows the user to select whether they want to save the mp3 as a ringtone or notification sound. My problem lies with the context menu. I want to be able to save a certain mp3 as a ringtone/notification based on which button they long press. How can you tell the `onContextItemSelected` which button was long pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Button that you are talking about corresponds to a `MenuItem`.

This MenuItem is passed to you in `onContextItemSelected()`.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Vikram. I had MenuItem already. I just don't know where to go from here. Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/